# Said the wrong brocho, now what?

Tags: halacha, blessing, tefilin, tallit-gadol

If someone was putting on his tallit and instead of saying the brocho on the talit he said the brocho on teffilin.
Then 10 seconds pass
What should he do (theoretically)?
Possible answers:

1. Take off his talis and put on his teffilin, then put on his talit with a brocho
2. Say baruch shaim kvod makchuso lolam vaed, and then say the brocho on the talit and teffilin as usual

Sources please

Comment: Teshuvo for saying a brocho in vain?

Comment: Generally, the recitation of a bracha does not nullify the mitzvah. I.e., I don't think it requires removing your tefillin. Whether you should say the proper bracha now that you have it on is a separate idea.